# Computing R2 values according to land cover types between 2 rasters in R?

Tags: r, raster, scatter-plot, tiff, r-raster

I have three rasters in r

```
> lpjre
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : xxx 
values     : 0, 21  (min, max)

> gcre
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 39.72  (min, max)
```

and a landcover raster

```
> tif4
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/XXXX/landusemaskedme.tif 
names      : landusemaskedme 
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
attributes :
       ID                          zn
 from:  1 evergreen needleleaf forest
  to : 12                   croplands
```

I plot a scatterplot between `lpjre` and `gcre` according to different land cover classes by

```
plot(lpjre[tif4==2],gcre[tif4==2])
```

I would like to find how can I compute the r2 value between `lpjre` and `gcre` according to land cover types?

I try this code and gives an error:

```
> cor(values(lpjre)[tif4==1], values(gcre)[tif4==1], use="complete.obs", method = 'pearson')
Error in values(gcre)[tif4 == 1] : invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

Reproducible rasters:

```
library(raster)
ras1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))
ras2 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))

#Generating landcover example data
raster2 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),ncol =3))
raster2 <- as.factor(raster2)

rat <- levels(raster2 )[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers")
levels(raster2 ) <- rat
```

Comment: can you please come up with a minimal *reproducible* example. Thus you make it more easy to help. Use e.g. `ras1 <- raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))` to generate rasters from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vector conversion for that. First a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(42)

ras1 <- raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
ras2 <- raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
lcc <- raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
ras1[] <- runif(100)
ras2[] <- runif(100)
lcc[] <- sample(c(1,2), 100, replace = TRUE)
```

Now you can convert the raster values into vectors by using `[]`. From there on you can use logical selection even between the rasters assuming they have corresponding geometric features.

```
cor(ras1[lcc[] == 2], ras2[lcc[] == 2], use = "complete.obs", method = "pearson")
# [1] -0.1644459
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to know how can I plot a regression line on the scatterplot b/w r1 and r2 based on the landcover types?

Comment: have you tried creating a linear model `lm(...)` and plotting that?

Comment: I have a bit confusion in that code. For instance, simple.fit = lm(ras1~ras2, data=dataset). What should be the dataset? Should I stack ras1 and ras2?

Comment: You should convert it to a data.frame before attempting to lm()

Comment: Through this code: scatter.smooth(x=ras1$df, y=ras2$df, main="scatterplot"),  I achieve lm of whole raster. How can I achieve lm according to landcover types? For instance I want to achieve scatterplot and lm b/w ras1 and ras2 but of land cover type 1 (which may stand for land)

Comment: You could use `as.data.frame(stack(ras1, ras2, lcc))` to acquire a dataframe with every row corresponding to one pixel and having the layers as columns. From there you can use standard subsetting and data analysis. For that you find a lot of help in other questions. I think they are better suited than this comment section.